# Length of dictionaries are not the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am creating a encryption key and a decryption key in two different dictionaries, however so I used a for loop like so:

I tried inverting same issue, I tried using value to search instead and print the key but it doesn't work for me

```py
encryptDict = {} 
cryptDict = {}
for i in range(len(charList)):
    x = random.randint(1,93)
    encryptDict.setdefault(charList[i], x)
    cryptDict.setdefault(x, charList[i])
```

I expect both length of dictionary to be the same 
but I get different length instead. this is an issue as the encryption is via character substitution. and the length of characters is 93

Comment: How does your `charList` looks like?

Comment: If it's character based... you might want to consider using `str.translate` with a custom made table built using `str.maketrans`...

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm still new to this, it's not character based, the elements in the list are string type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `random.randint` can repeatedly roll the same number, thus some of the `x` will be the same for different `i`, and the `cryptDict` will get a new `carList[i] value assigned for the existing key and thus end up being shorter.

Instead of repeatedly using `random.randint`, better use `random.shuffle` or `random.choice` *once* to roll all the `x` in one go without duplications and then iterate those values.

Comment: Thank you so much! But why does the first dictionary stores all 93 while the second dictionary doesn't?

Comment: @M.Hairul Well, assuming the values in `charList` are unique, then `encryptDict` will have unique keys, but some duplicate values, whereas `cryptDict` will have "duplicate" keys (except a dict can not have duplicate keys, thus overwriting existing keys instead).

Answer (score 0):

You're taking a random int in the range 1, 93, meaning that you can have *duplicates*. You should *shuffle* the indices. Something like

```
# zero based, use 1, len(charList) + 1 for one-based numbering
indices = list(range(len(charList)))
random.shuffle(indices)
encryptDict = dict(zip(charList, indices))
decryptDict = dict(zip(indices, charList))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But why does the first dictionary stores all 93 while the second dictionary doesn't?

Comment: @M.Hairul because you got duplicate **keys**, which map to different values but only the last stored is kept. This is why I use **shuffle** with a list made from range to ensure that there are no duplicates.